# Setup wizard for C# project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, setup-project, setup-wizard

I have a C# project that I've written using the .NET 4 framework, I've created an installation project using the setup wizard within the solution, the problem is that once the program is installed and I launch it, a dialog appears saying that the program is being configured and then starts the program, why is this? Is it necessary? How can i prevent this from appearing or happening altogether?

[image: An image of the program configuring]

**UPDATE**
I installed my application and launched the application from the .exe created in Program Files and a config window didn't appear and the app launched normally! How do i create a link to this shortcut without it showing the windows shown above? As i need to place a shortcut to the users startup folder.

Comment: Under add new projects, "Other Types" > "Setup and Deployment" > "Setup Wizard", Having a look through its properties etc, trying to find something relevant to the dialog above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Windows Installer detects missing resources. For example, some of the installed files were moved/removed/renamed or were installed per-user for another user account.

Here is an article with more details: http://setupanddeployment.com/general-installation-problems/preparing-install-popping/

You can use Event Viewer to determine which resource is causing this, like explained in the article I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out soon and declare it as a correct answer if problem=solved.

Answer (score 2):

The MSI file has auto-repair enabled. I don't think VS has an option to turn it off.

The shortcut links generated don't actually link to the files they should. They link to an executable in appdata. When that file's opened, it runs the installer repair check silently and opens the configuring dialog while any repairs take place. For some reason the installer thinks that files installed with your program are being deleted / corrupted. Perhaps temporary or configuration files?

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2007/08/20/select-play-select-3-0-select.aspx) given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865151/msi-auto-repair-issue-work-around) question should fix it if that's the case, but it'll still be activated if the user hits Repair in Add/Remove programs.